# Object Variable Error in Code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am receiving an object variable error when I run a Macro.

`Object Variable or with block variable not set`

This occurs on the second time I run the Macro through.  Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
' Select the first Junk Row and use it to delete all rows afterward
     With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Columns("F")
        .Find(What:="Total", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate - **Error occurs here.**
    End With
    A = ActiveCell.Row
    Range(A & ":" & LastRow).Delete
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  If I shut the program down it works fine the next time through.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Your `Find()` didn't find a match...

Comment: Not sure why it didn't I manually went through and saw there was a match.  Have since instituted a workaround by using another column however I would like to know why this is occuring.  Thanks.

Comment: Tim is right. also `.Find` argument `LookAt` is by default set to `xlPart` so if there really is `Total` in there, even if you have trailing or leading spaces, it will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Before activating the cell . its good to check whether the .find found the cell or not .. Below is the example .***

**Tested**

```
Sub testing()
Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Columns("F")
      Set rng = .Find(What:="Total", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues) 
    End With

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    A = rng.Row

    Range(A & ":" & LastRow).Delete

    Else

    MsgBox ("Total not found")

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you run the code it deletes the bottom rows **including the row containing "Total"**.  The second time you run the code it fails because the first pass deleted the "Total"

Answer (score 0):

Try and replace the

```
.find (...).activate
```

by:

```
.find (...).select
```

Even if i disagree with the use of select/activate.

simplest was

```
A= .find (....) .row  
'might return 0 or <nothing> or error , if no match ( .match is faster by the way)
```